# Total Time on Test (TTT) Statistic

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, ..., X_{(n)}$ denote an ordered sample of size $n$ from a life distribution. Let $T_n$ be the total time spent on test by the $n$ sample units until the failure of the longest living unit, so $T_n$ can be expressed as

$T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)}$,

i.e., as the area given by $n$ horizontal beams of length $X_{(i)}$, each having height equal to 1.

Based on this interpretation, we can defined

$T_i = \sum_{j=1}^i X_{(j)} + (n-i) X_{(i)}$.

Can you explain how do we derive the formula for $T_i$ from $T_n$? I don't understand why there is "$(n-1) X_{(i)}$" term.

Comment: Can you please clarify your notation, how can we prove a formula for $T_i$ when you did not give a clear definition?

Comment: At the time of the $i$th failure, $n-i$ units are still working and have been "on test" for a total time of $(n-i)X_{(i)}$.  Adding to that the total time on test for the $i$ units that have failed yields your formula the total time on test at the time of the $i$th failure.  If the failure rate is constant, it follows that $T_1, T_2, \dots$ are distributed as the arrival times in a homogeneous Poisson process.